# looping error in for loop if statement python

Tags: python-3.x

```
num = input()

id = list(result.keys())
print("key for "+ num +":")
for key in id:
   split = key.split('-')
    
   if num == split[0]:
        print(key)
   else:
        print("NOT FOUND")
```

this is part of my code

It returns key values and many lines of "NOT FOUND" together.

I believe I did some error in for loop but I'm stuck in it.

any suggests would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful if you spell out what input and output are expected. That could be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, `input` is a reserved keyword in Python - do not name your variables that.

Secondly, `result` is not defined here, but I'm assuming it's a dict initialized somewhere above.

I've refactored your code - hopefully changing the variable name fixes most of the errors:

```
inny = input()
print("Shape IDs for "+ the_input +":")
[print(str(k) if k.split('-')[0] == inny else "NOT FOUND") for k in list(result.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is also a name of built-in function you should avoid to use.

The else statement in your code is currently check and print for every key so there will be many lines of "NOT FOUND". I suggest using a variable to state whether the number is found and check this variable after checking all the keys.

```
idn = ["4-123", "4-456", "4-789"]

num = input()
print("key for "+ num +":")

found = False
for key in idn:
    split = key.split("-")    
    if split[0] == num:
        found = True
        print(key)

if not found:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Output:

```
4
key for 4:
4-123
4-456
4-789

1234
key for 1234:
NOT FOUND
```